# Bootstrap dropdown: Anchor tag used as Bootstrap dropdown button keeps its default behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code where I use an Anchor tag instead of a button in my Bootstrap dropdown. The problem is that, despite what is said [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/HTML_CSS/Bootstrap_Example/Button/Create_drop_down_button_with_anchor_and_UL.htm), when I click on the Anchor tag (labeled `Action`) the browser opens the Anchor tag instead of just opening the menu. In other words, the default behavior of the Anchor tag is not prevented.

We use Bootstrap v3 and this does not happen in all the environments, only in prod for now and sometimes on my local machines. This  happens accross all the known browsers i.e. Chrome, IE, FF for the desktop version, the non-desktop version does not have this functionality, so we did not test it there.

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Finally we used the following line of code to cancel out the default behaviour, but we never figured out the root cause of this happening only in one environment not in others:

$(".btn .dropdown-toggle").click(function(event){ event.preventDefault();})

Comment: will you please check the <a> tag custom style and also mention the device you used to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `href="#"`?

Use `href=""` instead of `href="#"`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter the value of href attribute, in neither case in works. Sometimes we even have values like "/portfolio/" instead  of the "#". The problem is the same code works in one envinronment not in the other one.  So the questiob is what causes the default HTML behaviour to be dominated in one environment not in the other one.

Comment: HTML is the same on all browser environments, excluding edge cases.Please add plunkr or fiddle and any other scripts you are using.

Comment: worth trying adding prevent defaults for the a tag `<a onclick="callback()"` `callback(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}`

Comment: Yes, the usage of onclick event to prevent the defalt behaviour  is my interim solution. But we are looking for a solution which can explain why this is happening only in the prod environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from the code

```
role="button"
```

Comment: I applied the change, no difference made.

Comment: Try creating a fiddle link and share here so it will be easy to debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

why is it an anchor?

you've missed out the data-target attribute as shown in the bootstrap documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns